# compare and join multiple tables but only show if there is a relation

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have multiple column that i need to compare and join.

This is the table i need to use to compare others.

**MainTable**

```
--Check Number-- --Reimbursement--
-----1000-----------5800.11
-----1001-----------5802.12
-----1002-----------5801.13
-----1003-----------5800.11
-----1004-----------5804.14
```

Multiple tables like this that I need to compare

**ChildTable1**

```
--Check Number --Name----Total Cash---Bonus-
-----1003------John-------5500.11------300
-----1000------Jane-------5502.12------300
-----1002------Joe--------5501.13------300
-----1001------Jay--------5500.11------300
-----1004------Janie------5504.14------300
```

**ChildTable2**

```
--Check Number --Name----Total Cash---Bonus-
-----1013------John-------5500.11------300
-----1010------Jane-------5502.12------300
-----1002------Joe--------5501.13------300
-----1011------Jay--------5500.11------300
-----1014------Janie------5504.14------300
```

The End Result should be like this

```
--Check Number --Name----Total Cash---Bonus-----Reimbursement--
-----1003------John-------5500.11------300-----------5800.11
-----1000------Jane-------5502.12------300-----------5800.11
-----1002------Joe--------5501.13------300-----------5801.13
-----1001------Jay--------5500.11------300-----------5802.12
-----1004------Janie------5504.14------300-----------5804.14
```

**not**

```
--Check Number --Name----Total Cash1---Bonus1---------Total Cash2---Bonus2-----Reimbursement--
-----1003--------John-------5500.11------300------------------NULL------NULL-----------5800.11
-----1000--------Jane-------5502.12------300------------------NULL------NULL-----------5800.11
-----1002--------Joe--------5501.13------300------------------NULL------NULL-----------5801.13
-----1001--------Jay--------5500.11------300------------------NULL------NULL-----------5802.12
-----1004--------Janie------5504.14------300------------------NULL------NULL-----------5804.14
```

So I need to compare all tables against the Main table and join only the tables with the same check number

Comment: What do you need to see if check number 1002 appears in ChildTable1 with Bonus 300 and in ChildTable2 with Bonus 200?  Are you sure it can never happen?  Why is check number 1002 in both child tables; what does it mean (or is it an accident with the data in the question)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as two separate queries and UNION them together:

```
select mt.CheckNumber as CheckNumber,
  c1.name as Name,
  c1.TotalCash as TotalCash,
  c1.Bonus as Bonus,
  mt.Reimbursement as Reimbursement
from MainTable mt
  inner join ChildTable1 c1 on c1.CheckNumber = mt.CheckNumber
UNION
select mt.CheckNumber as CheckNumber,
  c2.name as Name,
  c2.TotalCash as TotalCash,
  c2.Bonus as Bonus,
  mt.Reimbursement as Reimbursement
from MainTable mt
  inner join ChildTable2 c2 on c2.CheckNumber = mt.CheckNumber
```

Comment: But what if i'm dealing with a dynamic amount of child tables

Comment: If you have a static set of child tables you can create a view that UNIONs all of the child tables together, and join to that. If more child tables are added you can simply update the view definition.

Comment: Thanks I just tried this out.. I was breaking my head yesterday trying to figure this out. My mistake was joining all childtables at the same time than doing it individually

Comment: I'd be inclined to do MAINTABLE JOIN (Child1 UNION Child2 [UNION ChildN ...]), but the net result is basically the same.